# Package for multiple correlation?

Tags: python, correlation

Is there any easy to use python package that helps in calculating multiple correlation? Its definition is as follows:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_correlation

Answer (score 1):

Very similar question here:  [What to use to do multiple correlation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452353/multiple-correlation-in-python)

The answer given is an implementation using pandas.

Alternatively you could look at Numpy/Scipy, they likely have something you could use.  [numpy.corrcoef](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html) or [numpy.correlate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html) might get you started.

Comment: If you think it's a duplicate question, indicate so by voting to close it as such.

Comment: I don't think I'm allowed to yet.  Should I just not interact with questions that seem like duplicates then?

Comment: Even if you don't have enough reputation to actually vote for closing, you can always leave a comment to that effect.